# No Swap - Easy Way To Add?

Tags: partitioning, swap

My Ubuntu has no swap space. Apparently you can run a swap file on an existing partition - is that true?

I'd like to add one, but the online instructions are all rather complicated and require the terminal. I have no idea what I do there, so I avoid it.

Isn't there a utility that can sort out the swap thing - maybe a tweak in Gparted or something?

thanks,
James

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid console-voodoo and want to have ordinary swap partition then you should look into gparted application. You must shrink one of the existing partition to make room for swap partition, and then create new partition and format it as swap area.

After that, you must add your new swap to the */etc/fstab* file. Just add to it a line like that:

`/dev/sdX    none    swap    sw    0    0`

where /dev/sdX is a swap partition you have just created.

Comment: Thank you - that is much more straight forward. I'll try and report back.